# Killfocus for Combo Box (DDL)

Tags: .net, c#-2.0

Hi I cannot find it in the event pane/ Is it actually there? How can I add it?

Comment: WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is much too vauge.

You're probably looking for `Blur` or `LostFocus`.

Comment: LostFocus, still not present.

Answer (score 0):

Just get focus on other control or take a hidden field and then
controlName.Focus();

It will deviate focus from combo box.